# QT4: how to generate header files from ui

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2010, qt4

I'm working on a legacy project written in cpp under Visual Studio 2010. This is a desktop application built with QT4.

I'm an absolute beginner in the QT world, so maybe the question I'm going to ask is really trivial but I didn't find a simple solution to my problem.
As you can see from the screenshoot below (taken from the visual studio project), there are 15 "header" and "cpp" files which have the same name as the "ui" files, so I guess there is a way to automatically generate them. Do you know how to generate them? Because they are missing from the solution.

Thanks for reading

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use QtCreator?

Comment: That's an interesting suggestion. I'll give a look into that. Just a quick question: is QTCreator able to generate those files?

Comment: Yes and this is a very cool IDE when you use qt